# Can't install Firefox Developer Edition with apt-get

Tags: linux, firefox, apt-get, elementaryos

I already downloaded Firefox Developer Edition (38) and unpacked it from its tar.bzip2, but i don't like to have this application in my home directory. Also I'm running out of space in that partition, so I would like to install in the way that it should, with packages.

The official repositories points to the stable version of firefox (37). I tried to install the ppa for developer edition:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
```

with the following output:

```
gpg: anillo «/tmp/tmpln2b9B/secring.gpg» creado
gpg: anillo «/tmp/tmpln2b9B/pubring.gpg» creado
gpg: solicitando clave 247510BE de hkp servidor keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpln2b9B/trustdb.gpg: se ha creado base de datos de confianza
gpg: clave 247510BE: clave pública "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Mozilla Daily Build Team" importada
gpg: no se encuentran claves totalmente fiables
gpg: Cantidad total procesada: 1
gpg:               importadas: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Then run `apt-get update`.
In the tutorial that I follow, it claims that running sudo `apt-get install firefox` will replace firefox, but it doesn't happen. I also removed it, but it keep installing me the same stable version.

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using **ElementaryOS Luna**